# Comparison Vs Relational expressions in c++

Tags: c++

I was recently asked a question it was

"The expression `x<y` is called a(n)?"

1. Comparison expression.
2. Logical expression.
3. Arithmetic expression.
4. Relational expression.
5. None of the above.

I thought it was a comparison expression due to `<` however it was a relational expression. I've tried looking up difference and such for comparison and relational but I honestly think they are the same thing. 
Can someone explain to me the differences between the expressions?

Comment: ah I see, the person who asked me said it was their exam question, they guessed on the question and got it right, but didn't understand why.

Comment: They got it right because they chose the formal term instead of the colloquial one.

Comment: There's no such thing as comparison expression. Whoever uses this term is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about Relational expressions, see http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#rel

Comment: Please quote the relevant part of linked document.